# How to capture two letters?

Tags: regex, vba

I have the regular expression `[^&]_*\s*(SF)*\d{8}`

I am trying to match 8 digits with the word SF or SF_

Examples

1. _zz&69050398_5d147597dd4aca00014351d9_zz sf 76064603RPL_Import_Create
2. _ac&68728692_5d18fa52dd4aca00014356dd_SF 76113839  Copy of

The S from SF doesn't get highlighted and 8 digits before the third "_" gets highlighted as well. I need to avoid that.

You can see it here
https://regex101.com/r/P0P238/1/

Comment: What exactly do you expect to match out of the two examples you provided?

Comment: I think you could use `sf\s*\d{8}` with a case insensitive match. https://regex101.com/r/P0P238/2

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed from the example 1 I want to match sf 76064603 and for example 2 i want to match SF 76113839. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `[^&]_*\s*(SF)*\d{8}` you are matching not an ampersand `[^&]`, 0+ times `_`, 0+ times a whitespace char and capture in a 0+ times repeated group matching SF. Then pattern ends with matching 8 digits.

That means that there are a lot of "optional" parts which could match 0+ times.

You get your match because the `[^&]` can match the `F`, then `_*\s*(SF)*` is optional but the `\s*` can match the space and then the 8 digits can be matched.

You might update your pattern by removing the quantifier from the group and match `\s` and `_` in a character class `[\s_]`

```
[^&][\s_](SF) \d{8}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3YEkm/1)

If you just want to match 8 digits prepended with SF and a space, you could use a case insensitive match and use:

```
(sf) \d{8}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3YEkm/2)

Comment: Thank you very much you seem very knowledgeable in this subject. I have another question if you dont mind. I need the SF to be optional. sometimes i can have 8 digits or the leters SF and the 8 digits. I need to match all those cases. if I used  [^&][\s_](SF) \d{8} . It doesnt match the case when I only have "_76005473" in the third line here https://regex101.com/r/P0P238/1/ THank you very much for your time

Comment: @NataliaFontiveros Do you mean like this? `(SF)\s\d{8}|_\d{8}(?!\S)` See https://regex101.com/r/DHZrEu/1

Comment: Thank you like that